# How to get the state(enabled/disabled) of Safari App Extension from the containing macOS app?

Tags: safari-app-extension

I'm developing a Safari App Extension, which has to included with a [containing macOS app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension). When a user installs this app, the extension is added to Safari, but it's disabled by default. I can use `SFSafariApplication.showPreferencesForExtension` to direct users to the Safari preferences.

I'd also like to detect the state of the extension (enabled/disabled) to only ask to enable the extension if it's actually disabled and also to change the view in the containing app once it's been enabled. My extension is not a content blocker, so I don't think I can use `SFContentBlockerManager.getStateOfContentBlocker`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

This class allows to query extension state: [SFSafariExtensionManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionmanager/2122754-getstateofsafariextension) via its `getStateOfSafariExtension` method.

Swift 4 Example:

```
SFSafariExtensionManager.getStateOfSafariExtension(withIdentifier: ...) { (state, error) in
    if state?.isEnabled ?? false {
        // it's enabled
    } else {
        // it's disabled
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea about how to get notified when the extension is enabled or disabled?

Comment: Is there anything similar for iOS?