# How to get the state(enabled/disabled) of IOS Safari extension?

Tags: ios, safari-extension, safari-app-extension, safari-web-extension

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658109/how-to-get-the-stateenabled-disabled-of-safari-app-extension-from-the-containi) is about how to get the state of a macOS safari extension. Wondering how it can be done with **IOS** ? (In its app container aka via swift)

P.S: the mac code won't work on IOS as it gives:

```
Cannot find 'SFSafariExtensionManager' in scope
```

which the error makes sense as in [developer doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionmanager), IOS is not included.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out by any chance?